# Using jquery then to check that all ajax data is loaded.

Tags: jquery

I'm loading data from an XML hierarchy using ajax. First I load the parent file, then I loop through all nodes and loads another XML file for each node. I want to place the result from all these XML load's into a java object, then do something.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(getXmlFile('ansatt',request('meglerid'),writeEmployee)).done();
}); 

var items;

function writeEmployee(data){
    var def = [];
    _.each(data.children[0].children,function(item,key,list){
        //Get more data about each property
        var propid = findField(item,'oppdragsnummer');
        def.push(getXmlFile('oppdrag',propid,writeProperty));
    });
    $.when(def).done(function(){console.log('loaded ' + items.length)});
}

function writeProperty(data){
    items.push(data);
}

function getXmlFile (type,id, func){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/xml",
        url: "http://privatmeglerdrammen.no.er3.itum.com/site/privatmeglerdrammen.no/design/renderings/xml/" + type + id + ".xml",
        dataType: "xml"
        }).done(function (data){
            func(data);
        });
}
```

When all is said and done, the items array contains 119 elements, but the console.log('loaded ..') line outputs 0 elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: from the docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ it doesn't look like an array is supposed to be the argument of `$.when`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation for when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) there's this line (em mine):

> If a single argument is passed to `jQuery.when()` and it is not a Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and any doneCallbacks attached **will be executed immediately**.

You're passing an array of jqXHR objects. If you pass them one at a time, you'll get the logging you expect.

For example, using [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$.when.apply($, def).done(function() {/* insert logging */});
```

Comment: Unsure how you would do that, can you give an example using my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajaxStop() to run a function when all ajax calls are done: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    DoSomething();
});
```

Comment: I have other ajax calls working in paralell with these call's. Wouldn't ajaxStop force me to wait for ALL ajax calls to complete?